# Slow FIFO read from LSM6DS3

Tags: c, i2c, accelerometer, linux, st

I have been trying to read FIFO buffer from LSM6DS3 inertial sensor via i2c. The processor will read LSM6DS3 buffer every 20s so the FIFO will contain approximately 3120 bytes of accelerometer data. The sensor contains 2 registers to read FIFO data which are FIFO_DATA_OUT_L and FIFO_DATA_OUT_H.

In my host, I use read-write system call to communicate with the sensor. And My i2c clock is 400KHz also I have couple of other devices connected on the same bus.

```
i2c_init()
{
    fd_i2c4=open("/dev/i2c-4",O_RDWR);/*open i2c. fd_i2c4 is global*/
    if(fd_i2c4<0)
    {
        perror("i2c device open : ");
        BLOGV(LOG_TAG "i2c device open error");
        return -1;
    }
    if(ioctl(fd_i2c4,I2C_SLAVE,addr)<0)
    {
        perror("i2c slave error : ");
        BLOGV(LOG_TAG "i2c slave error");
        return -1;
   }
}
```

This is my i2c read function

```
static int32_t i2c_read_low_latency(int *file,__u8 reg,__u8 *buff,__u16 len)
{
    buff[0]=reg;
    int temp=write(*file, buff, 1);
    temp=read(*file, buff, len);
    if ( temp!= len) {
        /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
        printf("i2c read error \n");
      }
    return 0;
}
```

and FIFO reading function pseudo code,

```
fifo_read()
{
    int fifo length=get_fifo_data_level()  //to get number of available data in fifo.
    while(length-- >0)
    {
        i2c_read_low_latency(&fd_i2c4,LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_L,ch,2); // x axis data.
        i2c_read_low_latency(&fd_i2c4,LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_L,ch,2); // y axis data.
        i2c_read_low_latency(&fd_i2c4,LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_L,ch,2); // z axis data.
    }
}
```

The problem is it takes around 2-3 sec to read complete data. this consumes  lot of power. Any idea why this slow reading?.
link to data sheet [lsm6ds3](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6ds3.pdf)

Comment: Can you check the I2C communication on a scope once to see how long the actual communication is happening?

Comment: I cant directly probe the i2c line due to product hardware limitations. anyway, I will try with the LSM6DS3 development board.

Comment: What Linux system (hardware) are you using?

Comment: Qualcomm processor.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, your code is a regular Linux application, i.e. it runs in user space. Therefore, each call to `read` or `write` requires a context switch from user to kernel space. Most likely the process will also be paused while it waits for the answer from the I2C bus and needs to be rescheduled once the answer is ready. That has its cost.

Given your data, your code reads 3120 bytes from the sensor in about 2 seconds. Each byte requires two operations (a `read` and a `write` call):

```
2s ÷ (*3120* × 2) = 0.32ms
```

0.32ms sounds about right as the cost for the context switching and process scheduling. The I2C speed is bascially irrelevant. It's the pauses between the I2C transactions that make up the bulk of the cost.

To improve the speed, you will have to reduce the number of context switches, i.e. the number of I2C operations.

An easy solution to cut the number of operations in half is to use `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data`. It combines writing the regiser address and reading a value into a single operation.

Further optimization depends on the sensor. Usually, there is a way to read many bytes from a FIFO at once. If that's possible, `i2c_smbus_read_block_data` might be helpful. I'm not sure the LSM6DS3 supports it. Its documentation left me clueless.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about context switching. I have tried direct IOCTL calls and smbus_read/write calls but these took 3-4 sec. I cannot use SMBus block read since sensor has no option to read FIFO as blocks.

Comment: The idea is to replace the two IO operations (read and write) in `i2c_read_low_latency` with a single `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data` call. That should increase the speed. It doesn't sound as if that's what you have tried. And for the block read: Are you sure? Have you tried it?

Comment: I replaced my i2c_read_low_latency() calles with  res=i2c_smbus_read_word_data(fd_i2c4,LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_L);
but  no improvement

Comment: If context switching is limiting factor and if most significant 8 bit suffice then according to datasheet I think it is possible to disable automatic address increment and read whole fifo in one (two) context switch. If all 16 bits are needed then you will be limited by context switching or you could write/modify i2c driver. @code_numb

Comment: @Rokta That's the feature I was looking for in the datasheet. Can the address increment be configured via registers?

Comment: @Codo yes with register CTRL3_C, described on page 56

Comment: @Rokta: Thanks. So it's implemented then.

Comment: @Rokta According to the [Application Note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/12/98/b4/44/a5/bf/4e/c5/DM00157511.pdf/files/DM00157511.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00157511.pdf) *IF_INC* in *CTRL3_C* must be set to 1 for FIFO operation. So it cannot be used. However, chapter 8.4 gives some hints how to *retrieve entire FIFO content*. I still don't fully understand it. It seems to be possible but will require some tests.

Comment: @Codo You are correct, didnt notice this note. I think only possbility left is custom i2c driver.

Comment: @Codo according to chapter 8.4  the number of read operation required is equal to the number of unread samples in FIFO. So direct block reading is not possible.
I suspect that the sensor taking some time to load new data to the FIFO output register.

Comment: I am confused about the documentation. "read operation" in this context could mean separate I2C transaction or could mean read multiple bytes in a single I2C transaction. If the FIFO already contains many samples, the sensors doesn't need to acquire new samples. So no delay is needed.